# How can I move files to different Dropbox folders on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, dropbox

My specific need came from using a plaintext editor (Plaintext, although the issue is similar in IA Writer, Byword, etc.) where I can create new folders to organize my .txt docs, and I create new docs in them, *but I can't move existing ones into or out of folders.*

So I thought, surely I can switch over to the Dropbox app, move the files to the desired folders there, then come back, but that's not the case.   **There's not even a move function in the Dropbox app.**

Is there some way on an iPad to move a file in Dropbox to a different folder in Dropbox (that doesn't involve logmein or some other VPN app that lets me access my Mac)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a move function within the dropbox app.
Go to the folder that contains the file(s) you want to move and click on the *check icon*.

[image]

Select the file(s) you want to move and click on *move* on the lower right corner. Now a new window will appear. Choose the location where you want to move the file and tab the *choose* button.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: I don't know the correct English labels of the buttons (as you can see I use German language). Maybe somebody is willing to edit the post in order to have correct label names.

Answer (score 0):

## Goodreader

[Goodreader](http://www.goodiware.com) can do this easily. It is the swiss-armyknive for filehandling on the iPad and it supports a large number of storage servers.

From http://www.goodiware.com/gr-man-tr-servers.html#dropbox:

GoodReader offers you a server-style access to Dropbox. It allows you to browse your Dropbox account like a simple file server. You can download, upload, sync and delete files and entire folders.

GoodReader can publish individual files and folders from your Dropbox account. Select files and folders you want to share with others, press the Share button, and GoodReader will create a special public downloading link and send it via email.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I am using an apple macbook and this is the best video for that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuTH4qVqUhk